# Node js how to run axios.get every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I am kinda of a newbie to node js, Here is what i am trying to do:  i am looping through a json file full of links of our website via the map function (around 3000 links), inside the loop i am doing a axios get for each link and getting the response status code(will do other things in the future). But i want to run the axios get only like every 2 seconds or 5 seconds otherwise i am overwhelming the webserver. I am trying to input async await but it's still too fast and server is taking a hit (i am technically DDos-ing my own website). I put a SetTimeout around the axios but that doesn't seem like it worked, since in the console results are printing way too fast. **so the question is, how do i make each axios.get request wait every 2 seconds before running in the map loop?.**

```
var axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
var statusCheck = 0;

var main = [];
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/jay/Documents/crawl/filtered2.json');
let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);

jsonParsed.map(async(line) => {

    var encodeLink = encodeURI(line.link);
    const response = await axios.get(encodeLink).catch((err) => {
        var Status_ErrorsCatchaxios = {
            "status Code": err.response.status ? err.response.status : "No status code available",
            "Page title:": $('title').text() ? $('title').text() : 'No title avaialble',
            "Original Link": encodeLink ? encodeLink : "No Original Link Available",
            "errorCode": err
        }
        main.push(Status_ErrorsCatchaxios)
    })
    try {
        console.log(response.status)

        statusCheck = statusCheck + 1;
        console.log("Link: ", statusCheck)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[].map` function doesn't wait for your items to resolve, so your code is currently dispatching all the requests (as you said, around 3000) in parallel.

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead to only run one request at a time. For example:

```js
async function makeRequests (lines) {
  for (const line of lines) {
    const encodedLink = encodeURI(line.link)
    const response = await axios.get(encodedLink)
    // ...your response handling code here...
  }
}

makeRequests(jsonParsed)
```

If you want to wait for 2s between each request, you can add this line of code inside your `for...of` loop:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
```

#### Better solution

The solution above works, but I assume your webserver can probably take more than one request at a time, so maybe the ideal scenario would be to limit your code to make only up to *N* requests in parallel at a given time. This way you don't flood your server but you're able to get your results faster than just doing one request at a time.

The [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) NPM module allows you to do that with their [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) function.

This function receives your list of items as the first argument, a function that executes something and returns a promise for each item as the second argument, and an object with a `concurrency` key describing how many items you want to allow to be handled in parallel as the third argument.

Here's how it could work:

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird')

async function makeRequests (lines) {
  await bluebird.map(
    lines,
    async (line) => {
      const encodedLink = encodeURI(line.link)
      const response = await axios.get(encodedLink)
      // ...your response handling code here...
    },
    { concurrency: 3 }
  )
}

makeRequests(jsonParsed)
```

Comment: wow this seems to work , but code seems to get stuck around the 301th link? its not always 301 some time 180 sometime 402. Any idea why?

Comment: @jsPlayer The only reason I can see for it to stop before the end is if one of the requests fail, or part of your code throws an error when handling the response of a specific request (like trying to read some property of `null`). Try to add a try-catch statement to handle the error.

Answer (score 2):

Ditch the `map`, replace with a `for ... of`, await a promise that takes 2s to resolve, wrap everything inside an async IIFE for the await to be legal.

```js
// dummy data
const fakeJson = new Array(5).fill();
const fakeRequest = () => console.log(`request at ${new Date().toUTCString()}`);

// iteration with 2s in between
(async () => {
  for (let line of fakeJson) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    fakeRequest();
  }
})()
```

You can also use more classically use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) but HTTP requests are asynchronous, so might as well start with a structure that handles well async and loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting all at once because `.map`,`.forEach`,`.reduce` etc doesn't wait for the `Promise` to resolve. Use Simple For loop, it will wait for each promise to resolve or reject.

```
for(let i=0;i<jsonParsed.length;i++) {
    var encodeLink = encodeURI(line.link);
    const response = await axios.get(encodeLink).catch(...)
    try {
        ....
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
})
```

Why it doesn't work?
If we imitate the `forEach` loop it will be something like,

```
function forEach(arr, cb){
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        cb(arr[i], i, cb);
    }
}
```

So you see it doesn't `await` the `cb`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why timeout wont work in a loop is because it will fire all the requests/functions all at once after the `timeout` delay.

The idea is to **put delay in each iteration** and only after delay start the next iteration.

you can run a self invoking function which calls itself after the delay. So to run the function every 2 seconds, you can try this:

```
let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);
let len = jsonParsed.length;

(function requestLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
        let line = jsonParsed[len-i]
        var encodeLink = encodeURI(line.link);
        const response = await axios.get(encodeLink).catch((err) => {
            var Status_ErrorsCatchaxios = {
                "status Code": err.response.status ? err.response.status : "No status code available",
                "Page title:": $('title').text() ? $('title').text() : 'No title avaialble',
                "Original Link": encodeLink ? encodeLink : "No Original Link Available",
                "errorCode": err
            }
            main.push(Status_ErrorsCatchaxios)
        })
        try {
            console.log(response.status)

            statusCheck = statusCheck + 1;
            console.log("Link: ", statusCheck)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }                        
        let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);

        if (--i) requestLoop(i);     
   }, 2000)
})(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var i=0;
jsonParsed.map(async(line) => {
i++
setTimeout(async() => {

},i*2000)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use setTimeout function for running codes every 2 second!

```
setTimeout(async() => {
 // await postRequest()
},2000)
```