# Axios request automatically fired a second time after a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

In my nodejs application, I have an Axios API call that involves extensive operations and takes approximately 3 minutes to complete. The issue I'm facing is that, despite the initial call not encountering any problems or finishing its execution, a duplicate request is automatically triggered after approximately 2 minutes.

I haven't been able to identify the reason behind the automatic second call. My suspicion is that there might be a timeout mechanism causing a reissue of the request if the initial one doesn't complete within a certain timeframe.

Here's the code snippet:

```js
  @Get("/SchemaExp/:rd")
  @Authorized(["admin"])
  async SchemaExp(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, @Param("rd") rd: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log("SchemaExp route: ", new Date());
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get(`http://${MICROSERVICE_HOST}:${MICROSERVICE_PORT}/SE/` + rd, {
          headers: {
            token: req.cookies.token,
          },
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          reject(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {
          console.log("finally");
        });
    });
  }
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node js how to run axios.get every 2 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876990/node-js-how-to-run-axios-get-every-2-seconds)

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times before. Although the time may not be the same, the action is, so please check the previous questions. In any case, it may be dependent on "StrictMode".

Comment: Is it specifically this code which is causing the repeated request?  Or is whatever invokes this code repeating?  In your logging/debugging, what happens if you include a log output immediately before invoking Axios here?  Is that output logged for both requests?  If so then the problem may be further upstream than what we're seeing here.

Comment: I don't thing that is axios issue. Try check again your code again. If you are using development mode, try change to production mode and check again.

Comment: @David, it's this specific code. I've edited the post to provide more context. I attempted logging and debugging on both the server and microservice sides, and I discovered a new Axios request being fired after a lapse of time. I tested this endpoint in Postman, and I didn't encounter any problems. I've isolated the issue to this Axios call. Since I don't have an in-depth understanding of the Axios library, I thought I might be overlooking something in its usage

Comment: @GisCat: When the problem occurs, is `"SchemaExp route: ", new Date()` logged to the console only once?  Or is it logged for each Axios request being made?

Comment: @David it's logged only once at the first call